# Run time error using Rcpp using shared library

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have issues using Rcpp and R libraries when trying to use an embedded R instance within a shared library.

So for instance, this code snippet in a simple binary would run through correctly:

**main.cc**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Rcpp::NumericVector numeric_vector;
}
```

compiled with:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cc
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RInside/include/ -I/home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/ -I/usr/share/R/include/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cc"
Finished building: ../src/main.cc

Building target: rcpp_standalone
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RInside/lib/ -o "rcpp_standalone"  ./src/main.o   -lRInside -lR
Finished building target: rcpp_standalone
```

So now I would like to move my embedded R instance within a shared library. I have the following structure :

```
rcpp_shared
 |_ src
    |_ SharedObject.hh
    |_ SharedObject.cc
 |_ Debug
    |_ librcpp_shared.so

rcpp_binary
 |_ src
    |_ main.cc
 |_ Release
    |_ rcpp_binary
```

And the code look as follow :

## rcpp_shared

**SharedObject.hh**

```
#ifndef SHAREDOBJECT_HH_
#define SHAREDOBJECT_HH_

namespace namespace_a {

class SharedObject
{
public:
    SharedObject();
    ~SharedObject();

    void do_something();
};

}  // namespace namespace_a

#endif /* SHAREDOBJECT_HH_ */
```

**SharedObject.cc**

```
#include "SharedObject.hh"
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace namespace_a {

SharedObject::SharedObject() {}
SharedObject::~SharedObject() {}

void SharedObject::do_something()
{
    Rcpp::NumericVector numeric_vector;
}

}  // namespace namespace_a
```

That is compiled with:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/SharedObject.cc
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I../src -I/home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RInside/include/ -I/home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/ -I/usr/share/R/include/ -O0 -g3 -c -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"src/SharedObject.d" -MT"src/SharedObject.d" -o "src/SharedObject.o" "../src/SharedObject.cc"
Finished building: ../src/SharedObject.cc

Building target: librcpp_shared.so
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RInside/lib/ -shared -o "librcpp_shared.so"  ./src/SharedObject.o   -lRInside -lR
Finished building target: librcpp_shared.so
```

## rcpp_binary

**main.cc**

```
#include "SharedObject.hh"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    namespace_a::SharedObject shared_object;
    shared_object.do_something();
}
```

That is compiled with:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cc
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I../src -I../../rcpp_shared/src -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cc"
Finished building: ../src/main.cc

Building target: rcpp_binary
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L../../rcpp_shared/Release -L/home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RInside/lib/ -o "rcpp_binary"  ./src/main.o   -lrcpp_shared -lRInside -lR
Finished building target: rcpp_binary
```

But then when running rcpp_binary I have the following run time error / segmentation fault :

```
gdb ./Debug/rcpp_binary 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
[...]
Reading symbols from ./Debug/rcpp_binary...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mco/dev/workspace/debub_rcpp/rcpp_binary/Debug/rcpp_binary 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd72c9 in dataptr (x=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feff8>) at /home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:196
196 inline void* dataptr(SEXP x){
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bd72c9 in dataptr (x=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feff8>) at /home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:196
#1  0x00007ffff7bd733b in dataptr (x=0x20f8938) at /home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:199
#2  0x00007ffff7bd733b in dataptr (x=0x20f8938) at /home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:199
#3  0x00007ffff7bd733b in dataptr (x=0x20f8938) at /home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:199
#4  0x00007ffff7bd733b in dataptr (x=0x20f8938) at /home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:199
#5  0x00007ffff7bd733b in dataptr (x=0x20f8938) at /home/mco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:199
[...]
```

The gdb trace goes forever like that. Does anyone have a clue on what is happening and how I can make it work ?

## ** EDIT **

I removed the dependy to RInside and is crashes inside my libR.so.

```
gdb ./rcpp_binary 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[...]
Reading symbols from ./rcpp_binary...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/vagrant/test_rinside/rcpp_binary 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6eaf19d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libR.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6eaf19d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libR.so
#1  0x00007ffff6eb0cd7 in Rf_allocVector () from /usr/lib/libR.so
#2  0x00007ffff7bd7552 in Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::Vector (this=0x7fffffffe3e0) at /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:58
#3  0x00007ffff7bd6eca in namespace_a::SharedObject::do_something (this=0x7fffffffe41f) at src/SharedObject.cc:16
#4  0x00000000004008de in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe518) at src/main.cc:6
```

## ** EDIT 2 **

After installing r-base-code-dgb, the segmentation fault comes from a call to GetNewPage as you can see as follow. Dont know if it helps..

```
gdb ./rcpp_binary 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[...]
Reading symbols from rcpp_binary...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/vagrant/test_rinside/rcpp_binary 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
GetNewPage (node_class=node_class@entry=0) at memory.c:861
861 memory.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  GetNewPage (node_class=node_class@entry=0) at memory.c:861
#1  0x00007ffff6eb0cd7 in allocSExpNonCons (t=14) at memory.c:2112
#2  Rf_allocVector (type=14, length=0) at memory.c:2511
#3  0x00007ffff7bd7552 in Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::Vector (this=0x7fffffffe3e0) at /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:58
#4  0x00007ffff7bd6eca in namespace_a::SharedObject::do_something (this=0x7fffffffe41f) at src/SharedObject.cc:16
#5  0x00000000004008de in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe518) at src/main.cc:6
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using one of the standard Makefiles from the examples/ directory which are tested and work?

Comment: I will have a further look at those but basically I have lot more compiling around this part, so I would like to integrate those Makefiles into my existing ones. Any hint towards what to look for ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I check the Makefile from the examples, there is nothing different that the one I am using at the moment so far I can tell. Do you have an example that link a shared library ? All the example I saw are just "simple" binaries that works fine on my machine.

Comment: Looks more closely.  There are **six** subdirectories below `examples/` and MPI and Qt clearly need to be using other libraries.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I am not sure we are talking about the same thing. So fat I believe their is an issue using Rcpp / R inside a shared library. It is not a RInside related problem so to say.

Comment: There are 318 packages on CRAN using Rcpp. They all use Rcpp _via a shared library_ because that is how R loads them.  But you need to know how instantiation works, and just cobbling together a new Makefile is leading you to trouble. We don't claim you can randomly cobble; but we support clearly defined use cases. Yours doesn't seem to be one of them, but I do not see that as my issue.  You need to prove (to yourself) that what you claim actually works.